# A primality test using the gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be defined by 
   $$f(n) = gcd(n,\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor ! \mod n).$$

Show that

a) If $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$ with $p \leq \sqrt{n}$, then $p \mid f(n)$

b) If $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$ with $p \gt \sqrt{n}$, then $p \nmid f(n)$.

The ultimate goal is to show that a natural number $n \geq 2$ is prime iff $f(n) = 1$.

How can I prove this? Can I use the fact that $ gcd(n,\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor ! \mod n) = gcd(n,\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor ! )$ ?

Answer (score 1):

a) Show that $p$ divides both $n$ and $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor!$
b) Show that $p$ does not divide both of $n$ and $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor!$

For the ultimate goal, if $n$ is prime, then straight-forward calculation shows that $f(n) = 1$. On the other hand, if $n$ is not prime, then it *must* be divisible by some prime $\leq \sqrt{n}$ (why?), which means that $f(n)$ is divisible by the same prime, and therefore not equal to $1$.